# Is the brass brazier required for the Find Familiar spell, or can it be replaced by a spellcasting focus/component pouch?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, equipment, spell-components

When spell components are consumed or have a cost, they need to be provided and cannot be substituted by a spellcasting focus. The [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) spell has such components:

> 10 gp worth of charcoal, incense, and herbs that must be consumed by fire in a brass brazier

Now obviously, the charcoal, incense, and herbs have to be provided as they have a specified cost and are consumed. However, what about the brass brazier? Does the caster have to provide that as well, as there are components that have to be provided and they directly interact with the brazier?

It doesn't logically seem like something a component pouch could replace, mostly those things are some small items. On the other hand it seems unreasonable to carry a brass brazier around, sounds heavy.

---

A related question about the brass brazier: [What are the details surrounding the brass brazier required for the Find Familiar spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94676/what-are-the-details-surrounding-the-brass-brazier-required-for-the-find-familia)

Comment: Also relevant, although a brass brazier seems in a different league then the components mentioned here: [Does a material component cost for one component require all components involved for the spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100523/does-a-material-component-cost-for-one-component-require-all-components-involved)

Comment: Related on [The issue of burning hands needing two free hands](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46603). Not directly related, but indirectly that there are some "RAW" statement that don't make a ton of logical sense.

Answer (score 9):

#### RAW, you need either a brass brazier or a spellcasting focus.

The material component for *find familiar* states:

> 10 gp worth of charcoal, incense, and herbs that *must be consumed by fire in a brass brazier*.

This is oddly specific language for something that isn't required at all. The *rules-as-written* ruling is abundantly clear here: the charcoal, incense, and herbs *must* be consumed by fire in a brass brazier. Or, alternatively, a spellcasting focus can substitute for the brass brazier only, not the charcoal, incense, and herbs:

> A character can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus (found in chapter 5, “Equipment”) in place of the components specified for a spell. But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell.

Since a cost for the brazier is not given, the brazier can be replaced by a component pouch or spellcasting focus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117851/discussion-between-nautarch-and-findusl).